# PHP MSSQL Query not executing

Tags: php, sql-server

I have an mssql query in php which does not seem to be executing.

Does anyone have any idea's? When running profiler on SQL, all I see is the database being selected.

```
$sth = mssql_query("ALTER TABLE " & $tablename & " ADD " & $newfield & " " & $type);

$save = mssql_query("INSET INTO SD_FIELDS (COLUMN_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME, SEQ_TABLE, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_TYPE)
                        values ('" & $newfield & "', '" & $displayname & "', " & $tableseq & ", '" & $datatype & "', '" & $type & "'");


if ($sth) 
{
    if ($save) 
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = $save;
    }
} 
else 
{
     $response["success"] = 0;
     $response["message"] = $sth;
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages? Look in your server logs.

Comment: On your second query, is the "INSET" typo in your real code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `&` with `.`

Should be like this: `'" . $var . "'`